# Decode back from base64 to get the name of the file

Tags: angular, spring-boot, base64

The issue that I'm having is I need to have access to the name of the image that I am displaying. I'm using spring-boot for my backend, here is how I am getting my images:

```java
public List<String> readImages() throws IOException {
   return Files.list(Paths.get(context.getRealPath("/images")))
          .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
          .map(this::encode)
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
        
private String encode(Path file) {
   try {
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getFileName().toString());
        String encodeBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Files.readAllBytes(file));
        return "data:image/"+extension+";base64,"+encodeBase64;
   } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
   }
}
```

My `.html`:

```html
<div class="col-6" *ngFor='let image of images'>
    <img [src]="image" class="img-thumbnail">
</div>
```

How do I get the name of the image that is being sent? Also, how do I display a particular image instead of... all of them?

Comment: if you read your backend code, you can see that only the extension of the filename is taken and put into the data url. The base64 encoded data is only the content of the file (i.e jpg/png or whatever image data). You won't find the file name in it.